# JavaCC IntegerLiteral

Tags: javacc

I am using JavaCC to build a lexer and a parser and I have the following code:

```
TOKEN:
{
   < #DIGIT : [ "0"-"9" ] >
  |< INTEGER_LITERAL : (<DIGIT>)+ >
}


SimpleNode IntegerLiteral() :
{
  Token t;
}
{
(t=<INTEGER_LITERAL>)
{
    Integer n = new Integer(t.image);
    jjtThis.jjtSetValue( n );
    return jjtThis;
}
}
```

Hence it should accept only integers but it is also accepting 4. or 4 %%%%%% etc.

Comment: If `IntegerLiteral` is the start symbol for your parser, you need to add `<EOF>` after `t=<INTEGER_LITERAL`.

Comment: when I add <EOF> it says expected EOF and accepts no other input

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer what language you want your parser to recognize. So far we know that "4" is in the language, but "4." and "4%%%" are not. Also that the language includes more than `(<DIGIT>)+`.  That's not much to go on.

Comment: what do you mean? integer on it's own should work though

Comment: I mean that your question is not clear because you haven't made it clear exactly what set of strings needs to be accepted. Please rewrite the question to make it clearer what should and should not be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try turn on debugging in your parser spec file like:

```
OPTIONS {
  DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER=true
}
```

This will create a printout of what the TokenManager is doing while parsing.

Answer (score 0):

"4." and "4%%%%" are not really accepted because what is read by your parser is always "4"
if you set you *DEBUG_PARSER = true;* in the OPTION section you will see the currently read token.
I think if you change your grammar like this you can see that it throws a TokenMgrError when it reads the unhandled character

```
    SimpleNode IntegerLiteral() :
    {
      Token t;
    }
    {
    (
        t=<DIGIT>
    {
        Integer n = new Integer(t.image);
        jjtThis.jjtSetValue( n );
        return jjtThis;
    })+
    }
```